# Calendar implementation to web app

Tags: web, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a web app (a service with 2 types of users: doctors and patients). The user data is stored in a database. Users are logged in by email and password.

I need to add a possibility for users to have calendars on their personal pages. Every user could manage his own schedule.

Some questions:

1. Generally, what is the best way to do this? Is there any step-by-step guide?
2. If I use google calendar, is there is an opportunity to have one google account for the whole service (like a database of calendars). So user would not need to have his own google account and would have a permission to only change his own calendar based in the service account. I've read some info  [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) but not sure if I got the concept right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js). You need a Python 2.4 or greater to provide a web server. The `origin_mismatch` error will occur during the authorization flow if the host and port used to serve the web page doesn't match an allowed JavaScript origin on your Google Developers Console project. Make sure you completed the [Step 1.e](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name) and that the URL in your browser matches.

Also, as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth), every request your application sends to the Google Calendar API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/#google-sign-in), some aspects of authorization are handled for you.